# D3 v4: Determine which property to extract from geoJson depending on click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "prop1": "val1", "prop2": "val2", "prop3": "val3" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [
                [
                    [168.77944820788511, 672.173755174731468],
                    [278.300419534049979, 672.173755174731468],
                    [278.300419534049979, 590.815319332437525],
                    [168.77944820788511, 590.815319332437525],
                    [168.77944820788511, 672.173755174731468]
                ]
            ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "prop1": "val1", "prop2": "val2", "prop3": "val3" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [
                [
                    [282.211882795699466, 672.369328337813613],
                    [334.625490501792683, 672.369328337813613],
                    [334.625490501792683, 591.01089249551967],
                    [282.211882795699466, 591.01089249551967],
                    [282.211882795699466, 672.369328337813613]
                ]
            ] } }
   ]
}
```

Above is an extract of a geoJson file that contains `geometry` data on how to draw some paths on the page. Each path also has `properties` describing characteristics of the path (e.g. `prop1`, `prop2`, and `prop3`.

In my page there is also a list of links, each of which has an `id` attribute that corresponds to one of properties in the geoJson file.

```
<ul>
    <li id="prop1"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li id="prop2"><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li id="prop3"><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like my code to do:

- when the user clicks on a link extract its `id` [1]
- use that `id` to extract the value of the corresponding property in the geoJson [2]
- use that value to assign an attribute `status` to the path, that I will use later to style the paths [3]

I am stuck at the second point, because I cannot define which property should be extracted depending on the `id` extracted).

```
//OPTION 1
d3.select('#myList').selectAll('li').on('click', function () {
propPicked = this.id
propPicked = 'd.properties.' + propPicked //[1]
d3.selectAll('path').each(function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('status'. function (d) {   //[3]
        return propPicked   //[2] this is where I am stuck
    })
})

//OPTION 2
d3.select('#myList').selectAll('li').on('click', function () {
propPicked = this.id //[1]
d3.selectAll('path').each(function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('status'. function (d) {   //[3]
        return d.properties[propPicked]   //[2] this is where I am stuck
    })
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This solution should help you get the properties from each object in the array in its own `properties` array.

```
var selectedProperties = [];
d3.select('#myList').selectAll('li').on('click', function () {
var propPicked = this.id; // e.g., "prop1"
d3.selectAll('path').each(function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('status'. function (d) {
        selectedProperties.push(d.properties[propPicked]);
    })
})

console.log(selectedProperties); // ["val1", "val1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to a different solution on my own, which I will post it just for reference.

```
d3.select('#myList').selectAll('li').on('click', function () {
    //extract selected property from button
    propPicked = this.id;
    //extract rooms status for that period
    d3.selectAll('path').attr('status', function (d) {
        return d.properties[propPicked];
    });
    nextFunction()
})
```